# TypeError: callback is not a function error callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep running into this callback error while trying to test posting data to my database. I am unsure of the cause and have been trying to debug for a bit. Might be because I am passing it an error and submitError is undefined? It seems to be hooked up correctly in my method.

One of the callbacks at the bottom of the code is giving me the error. It is the catch callback telling me callback is not a function. I have this same code running fine in another project.

```
import axios from "axios"

import apiBaseUrl from "../../utils/apiBaseUrl.js"

export default function(title, customer, description, billed, tags, location, notes, images, jobtype, callback) {
  axios.post(`${apiBaseUrl}/jobs/create-new`, {
        title: title,
        customer: customer,
        description: description,
        billed: billed,
        tags: tags,
        location: location,
        notes: notes,
        jobtype: jobtype,
        images: images
  }, {
    withCredentials: true
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    callback(response.data)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    callback({submitError: true})
  })
}
```

This is the api side:

```
createNewJob: function(title, customer, description, billed, tags, location, notes, images, jobtype, callback) {
    JobModel.findOne({$or: [{title: title}, {customer: customer}]}).exec(function(error, job) {
      if (error) {
        callback({submitError: true})
      } else if (job) {
        callback({alreadyExistsError: true})
      } else {
        const arrayOfTags = tags.split(",").map(function(tag){
          return tag.trim()
        })
        const arrayOfNotes = notes.split(",").map(function(note){
          return note.trim()
        })
      }

      const newJob = new JobModel({
        id:randomstring.generate(12),
        title: title,
        customer: customer,
        description: description,
        billed: billed,
        tags: arrayOfTags,
        location: location,
        notes: arrayOfNotes,
        jobtype: jobtype,
        images: images
      })

      newJob.save(function(saveError) {
        if(saveError) {
          callback({submitError: true})
        } else {
          callback({success:true})
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: The code that adds `callback` to the function parameters is missing from your question. You should add it. It may well be that `callback` is not a function. You should probably give your function a name.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Tangentially related, but functions w/ long, position-based parameter lists are somewhat brittle and difficult to reason about. You may want to consider passing a parameter object instead, and keep the `callback` parameter separate, since it's not part of the customer.